# Is it possible to capture the window messages/events inside the Translate/Dispatch Message loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is it possible to capture the window `messages/events` inside the `Translate/Dispatch Message loop`?

this is the Message process method for the window

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        PressedKey[wParam] = true;
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        PressedKey[wParam] = false;
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and here is `Translate/Dispatch Message loop`

```
void MyScreen::RunScreenMainLoop()
{
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        //I wanna handle the messages here as well!
        switch (msg.message)
        {
        case WM_SIZE:
            show("size event called");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

but it never goes inside the switch statement , is there a work a round to do this?

Comment: So add code that handles the messages in your message pump. Usually not a very good idea though as it can cause the message pump to delay.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious it doesn't work I do a `switch(msg.message)` but it never breaks there!

Comment: That's the kind of code that should be included in your post, an example of exactly what you're trying to do with a description of how it's not working.

Comment: Sure.  And this is common for handling keystrokes that need to be detected no matter what window has the focus.  Like F1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan am not asking you why it's not reaching this point , I have debugged it , it goes only inside `if(Peek){} else{}` , but not when I check the `msg.message`!, so before judging read -.-

Answer (score 3):

One obvious problem appears to be that you are reading `msg.message` before it has been initialized. Note that you are reading `msg.message` before calling `PeekMessage`. Of course, since we cannot see where `msg` has been declared, perhaps the real code doesn't suffer this problem.

Now, the main issue is that `WM_SIZE` is not a queued message and does not arrive via the message queue. There is an important distinction between asynchronous queued messages like input messages, timer messages, paint messages, and synchronous messages that are delivered direct to the window procedure. And `WM_SIZE` is non-queued, synchronous.

You can learn that this is so from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) which says:

> A window receives this message through its WindowProc function.

You won't catch it with `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage` etc. The way to intercept this message is from code inside the window proc.

To learn more about queued and non-queued messages, you can start with this topic from MSDN: [About Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

That is not how your message loop should look.  Try this instead:

```
void MyScreen::RunScreenMainLoop()
{
    MSG msg;
    while (1)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then intercept messages for specific windows by subclassing those windows:

[Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MySubWndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            show("size event called");
            break;

        case WM_NCDESTROY:
          RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, MySubWndProc, uIdSubclass);
          break;

        // other case statements as needed...
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); // will dispatch the message to MsgProc()
}
```

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
SetWindowSubclass(hWnd, MySubWndProc, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You make a good point about the loop, `GetMessage` will yield the CPU if there are no messages while `PeekMessage` won't. That leads to a greedy processor hog.

Comment: On the other hand, for things like game loops, it does make sense to use `PeekMessage()` instead of `GetMessage()`, as such loops do need to do other processing in between messages. However, that does not change the fact that messages should still be handled in (subclassed) window procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the message pump, so you can freely add code to process messages in you rmessage loop. For instance, if you don't want `WM_CHAR` conversion, don't call `TranslateMessage()`. [If you want normal windows to have dialog-style tab navigation, call `IsDialogMessage()`.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx) [You can literally go crazy here.](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/745fdc9dc6f7f0e59ba2e372327d59cf899929ca/uitask_windows.c#L6-L97)

Thread messages work in the same way. Thread messages don't have a window, so `DispatchMessage()` does nothing to them. You have to handle those in your message pump.

However, keep in mind that if you enter a dialog box or something else that uses its own message pump, your customizations will be lost. [Here's an explanation that uses thread messages.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/27/412565.aspx)

MFC, ATL, Qt, WPF, etc. may also have their own message pump setups that you have to watch for (or their own message pumps, period, in which case you'll have to see if the API provides a hooking mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna handle your messagens in loop, is just access the MSG for get your messages information, like this:

```
 void MyScreen::RunScreenMainLoop()
{
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        // Handle here your messages
        if (msg.message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) // Mouse Left Button Event
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"You Clicked!", L"Info", MB_OK);
        }
        //
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
//do other stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that is not working , it nevers hit the `MessageBox`